# How to make a list of vectors from a 2 columns data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, split

I'm having a hard time trying to transform my data frame to a list of vectors were it's name is the string in the first column in the data frame and the vector itself is the already vector in the second column of my data frame.

I have this data frame:

```
> head(df)
     Intron.ID
1 AT1G79930.2 
2 ATCG00720.1 
3 AT1G02080.2 
4 AT4G32551.2 
5 AT5G66190.1 
6 AT1G51720.1 
                                                                                                    Sequence.s.
1                                                        ['GAGGTGCTTGCAAATCGTTCACATCACTGTACTGCACATCAACAGAGAAT']
2  ['GCTTCTTTGTATTTTATGTTTTTAGTCATTATAGCTTTTTTTTTGAATAA', 'TGTTTGAGCTGTACGAGATGAAATTCTCATATACAGTTCTTGGAGGGGGG']
3                                                        ['CTCACCCGGAGTTAGTCACTGTTATTGAACAAGCACTTTCAAGGATATCA']
4                                                        ['AAGTGGTGGTATGTCTCCACAGGTTCAAACTCGAAATCAGCAACTTCCTG']
5                                                        ['AAGGGTTCTTAGGTTTGAATTTGTTGACAACAATCCCTTCTTCCTGTTTC']
6  ['ATTTGGCTTCTCACATAACACTGAAGCTGTGTGACTTGTGTACAATTTTG', 'CTGAGTTAATCTAATAAGCAAGATACATTTTACTTTCGTTTTCCTCTTCC']
```

And I need this output:

```
$AT1G79930.2
[1] "GAGGTGCTTGCAAATCGTTCACATCACTGTACTGCACATCAACAGAGAAT"

$ATCG00720.1
[1] "GCTTCTTTGTATTTTATGTTTTTAGTCATTATAGCTTTTTTTTTGAATAA" "TGTTTGAGCTGTACGAGATGAAATTCTCATATACAGTTCTTGGAGGGGGG"

$AT1G02080.2
[1] "CTCACCCGGAGTTAGTCACTGTTATTGAACAAGCACTTTCAAGGATATCA"

$AT4G32551.2
[1] "AAGTGGTGGTATGTCTCCACAGGTTCAAACTCGAAATCAGCAACTTCCTG"

$AT5G66190.1
[1] "AAGGGTTCTTAGGTTTGAATTTGTTGACAACAATCCCTTCTTCCTGTTTC"

$AT1G51720.1
[1] "ATTTGGCTTCTCACATAACACTGAAGCTGTGTGACTTGTGTACAATTTTG" "CTGAGTTAATCTAATAAGCAAGATACATTTTACTTTCGTTTTCCTCTTCC"
```

The closest I got to that result was with the following command:

```
> df2 <- split(df, df[1])

> head(df2)
$`AT1G01760.2 `
      Intron.ID                                             Sequence.s.
11 AT1G01760.2   ['ACCGGTTGTTCCAAGAATAACTTCGTGTAAGCCAGAATAGTTCCAACACA']

$`AT1G02080.2 `
     Intron.ID                                             Sequence.s.
3 AT1G02080.2   ['CTCACCCGGAGTTAGTCACTGTTATTGAACAAGCACTTTCAAGGATATCA']

$`AT1G04430.2 `
     Intron.ID                                             Sequence.s.
9 AT1G04430.2   ['CATTATGAACGGCATTGTCCTCCTCCCGAAAGACGGTTTAATTGTTTGAT']

$`AT1G06150.1 `
      Intron.ID                                             Sequence.s.
45 AT1G06150.1   ['TGCTAGTGGATCCGTAAGTGCCAAAAATAAATGCCTGATATGAGTCACCA']

$`AT1G17680.3 `
      Intron.ID                                             Sequence.s.
48 AT1G17680.3   ['GCAAGCACCAGCTTTCGATATAGCATACTATTACCTTTCACGTGTTTCTG']

$`AT1G18470.2 `
      Intron.ID                                             Sequence.s.
81 AT1G18470.2   ['TTCCTTCGTCAATTGACCACCAACCTAATAGCCTGGAACCATGGTGCAAG']
```

It got it all wrong: the sequences are not in to the right name assignment and some sequences are missing. It is not a good solution...

Extra information as requested (I added the 2 '...'):

```
> dput(head(df))
structure(list(Intron.ID = structure(c(15L, 80L, 2L, 58L, 79L, 
9L), .Label = c("AT1G01760.2 ", "AT1G02080.2 ", "AT1G04430.2 ", 
"AT1G06150.1 ", "AT1G17680.3 " ...), class = "factor"), Sequence.s. = structure(c(49L, 
59L, 39L, 3L, 2L, 15L), .Label = c(" ['AAACACAAGGGTGGGGTTGACTCTCAAACTCACAAAAAGTTACATTTTCT']", 
" ['AAGGGTTCTTAGGTTTGAATTTGTTGACAACAATCCCTTCTTCCTGTTTC']", " ['AAGTGGTGGTATGTCTCCACAGGTTCAAACTCGAAATCAGCAACTTCCTG']", 
" ['AATCCATAAAGAAAATGGAGGAGAACATTCAGAATCTGGAAGGTAAGAAC', 'GATTTATGCTTTGGCAACAAAGAGTAGTCATATTCCATACAGGAACTCAA']", 
" ['AATTGATCCAGATTGTAGATTAATTGGACTCCATCTGTATGACGGCTTGT']" ...
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

So, how can I do that transformation without passing the header 'Intron.ID' and 'Sequence.s.' to the vectors and just keep the sequences inside the vector (in the right order and assignment), not including the Intron.ID?

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Thank you all in advance.

Cordially,

Fernanda Costa

Comment: Do you have a `list` in the second column?

Comment: You can try `split(df, seq(nrow(df)))`

Comment: Hello Sotos, thank you for your reply! It solved the sequence attribution problem, now each vector has the right sequences, but how can I have the vectors without passing the headers and the first column of the data frame?

Comment: I m not sure. I need to see a reproducible example in order to be able to help you any further. You can use `dput(head(df))` to create one.

Comment: Hello @akrun, thank you for your reply. Yes, i have a list in the second column.

Comment: Try `with(aggregate(.~ Intron.ID, df, c), split(Sequence.s., Intron.ID))`

Comment: @akrun Almost! Instead of the sequences, it got me the number of characters inside the list (i think):
`> head(with(aggregate(.~ Intron.ID, df, c), split(Sequence.s., Intron.ID)))
$AT1G01760.2
[1] 7

$AT1G02080.2
[1] 39

$AT1G04430.2
[1] 24

$AT1G06150.1
[1] 75

$AT1G17680.3
[1] 54

$AT1G18470.2
[1] 78`

Comment: @FernandaCosta  When you post `dput` use the full structure, instead of clipping it

Comment: Just added the dput command output @Sotos

Comment: @FernandaCosta  If you copy the dput output from the edit and paste it on the console, you will understand the issue

Comment: @akrun I got from the dput that the command i'm using to make the vectors don't get the full structure of the sequences, it misses the label part. Is that correct? I'm trying to figure out how to call the full structure to the vector. Any tips, please?

Comment: ok, is it a regular data.frame or some other object